# Add Velocity Relative To Object

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

I am trying to make a train in js but i want add the velocity to the train.
but the train has an other axis relative to the canvas so  how can i add the velocity relative to canvas
http://snapsoft.eu/example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If train system is rotated relative to stationary system by angle Theta, then you can transform velocity vector `Vr` (in rotated) to `Vs` (in stationary):

```
Vs.X = Vr.X * Cos(Theta) -  Vr.Y * Sin(Theta)
Vs.Y = Vr.X * Sin(Theta) +  Vr.Y * Cos(Theta)
```

If rotated system moves with velocity W, then add W also

```
Vs.X = W.X + Vr.X * Cos(Theta) -  Vr.Y * Sin(Theta)
Vs.Y = W.Y + Vr.X * Sin(Theta) +  Vr.Y * Cos(Theta)
```

In your example

```
Theta = -Pi/4
Vs.X = 0.5 * 0.707 +  0 * 0.707 = 0.3535
Vs.Y =  - 0.5 * 0.707 +  0 * 0.707 = -0.3535
```